# Calculate overtime duration in SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-function

I tried to calculate the OT Duration. But I can't find the solution. Could you guys help me how to calculate it.
Here is my query:

```
CASE 
    WHEN T.ScheduleId IS NULL OR T.HolidayName IS NOT NULL OR T.CheckIn IS NULL OR T.CheckOut IS NULL OR DATEDIFF(MINUTE, T.WorkingTimeTo, T.CheckOut) < CAST(@MinOTDuration AS INT) THEN 0
    WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, T.WorkingTimeTo, T.CheckOut) < CAST(@MaxOTDuration AS INT) THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, T.WorkingTimeTo, T.CheckOut)
    ELSE
        CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, T.WorkingTimeFrom, T.CheckIn) > CAST(@LateInGracePeriod AS INT) THEN CAST(@MaxOTDuration AS INT) 
            ELSE CAST(@EntitledOTDuration AS INT)
        END
END / 60.0 AS OTDuration
```

[From that query, the result is 0.00](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XBiA.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Could you give the parameter values you are using?